# Inserting line breaks before numbers in a text

Tags: java, php, string

I have a text that consists of more than 6000 lines but I have copied it from a PDF and I had to remove all line breaks because in the PDF there are extra line breaks at the end of each visible line.

So now I ended up with something like `1. textextexttexttexttext2. texttexttexttexttext3. texttexttexttext4. texttexttexttext ... texttexttext199. texttexttext200. texttexttext`

The questions now is how do I put line breaks only in front of the numbers with a dot and space after them in order to get:

```
1. textextexttexttexttext
2. texttexttexttexttext
3. texttexttexttext
4. texttexttexttext
... texttexttext
199. texttexttext
200. texttexttext
```

Would be nice to have the algorithm in PHP or Java.

Comment: You can't ask people to do your work, propose an algo before then ask if it's right or if it can be improved.

Comment: talnicolas, that's the T-Shirt I'm wearing right now :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the regex

```
(\d+\. )
```

by

```
\n$1
```

Or

```
(?=\d+\. )
```

by

```
\n
```

Answer (score -1):

Double line breaks sounds like a windows carriage return + linefeed combo (CR+LF) (asc 13, asc 10). Perhaps take the original copy+pasted text and replace all instances of `\r\n` with `\n`

Comment: PDFs usually (with exceptions) store glyphs and positions for them to describe the page layout. Therefore the plain text is usually (with exceptions) lost. What you copy there is Acrobat's best guess regarding the original text and things like spaces, line breaks or hyphenation are always problematic.

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to say here. If you can copy the text from a pdf and save it to a text file, the resulting line breaks will be cr+lf on a windows machine.

Comment: So what? This has nothing to do with the problem they're describing and trying to solve. Heck, it's not even about CRLF or any other kind of line break *at all*.

Comment: "I have copied it from a PDF and I had to remove [...] extra line breaks at the end of each visible line". You may be aware that sometimes people do things on one OS and then work remotely on a linux or unix server which treats CR+LF differently, dpending on tool, configuration and environment.